# Need help with a math trick question

Tags: algorithm, math

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Easy interview question got harder: given numbers 1..100, find the missing number(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492302/easy-interview-question-got-harder-given-numbers-1-100-find-the-missing-number)

Hi guys, I wasn't sure where to ask this but since this is an algorithmic question here it goes. I've come face to face with a math problem and can't seem to get over it for the last couple of days. It goes like this:

> You are given an adding machine that
>   sums a set of N+1 digits consisting of
>   positive integers 1 to N as it's given
>   the numbers (e.g. the machine is given
>   3 as the first number and outputs 3.
>   It's then given 6 as the second number
>   and outputs 9. It's given 11 as the
>   third number and outputs 20. Etcetera
>   until it has processed N+1 numbers).
>   One (and only one) of the digits is
>   repeated. How do you determine which
>   number is repeated?

It seems like a trick question and I'd be really annoyed if it is just that a question to which the answer is 'not possible' - any ideas here?

Comment: You could ask this question here http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It is not made clear in your question, but I presume that you are given the total, but not N.  (If you were given N, this would be a ridiculously simple problem.)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492302/easy-interview-question-got-harder-given-numbers-1-100-find-the-missing-number (which also discusses a more general version)

Comment: let say we have both the SUM and N

Comment: Do you mean digits or numbers?

Comment: I don't get it. Can someone please clarify the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subtract (1+2+..+N) = N*(N+1)/2 from the sum.

EDIT: in case N is not known, find the largest triangular number smaller than the given sum and subtract.

Comment: doesn't seem to work... N refers to the number of numebrs and not a value on its own.

Comment: no wait I don't get it lets assume teh numbers were added as 3, 6, 11, 6 - so now N is 4. How can I tell given that I enter 6 and only have the sum of the values?

Comment: @Ali: from your description: " a set of N+1 digits consisting of positive integers 1 to N". But 6 and 11 are outside 1..4.

Comment: uh how so I mean I got this question on a job interview and have reproduced it in its entirety. I'm a bit perplexed as to what N+1 refers to it seems boyond my realm of mathematics or I'm forgetting my numerical methods classes here...

Comment: This is how I read the question: summed numbers: [1,2,3,3,4], N = 4; sum = 13, 13-4*5/2 = 13-10 = 3

Comment: @Ali: There are N numbers from 1 to N; N of the numbers it sums are unique; therefore by the pigeonhole principle it sums all the numbers from 1 to N. Plus an additional number which is repeated. Given N (and it seems we are), this question isn't really a trick.

Comment: ah - I got it - was reading the question wrong it seems..

Answer (score 1):

If you know `N` and the sum `S`, the answer is `d = S - N*(N+1)/2`.
This is because the sum of all numbers from 1 to N is a [triangular number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_number), and each number from 1 to N occurs once (except for one that is repeated).

If you do not know N, you can take `N = floor((sqrt(8*S+1)-1)/2`. That can be deduced from a quadratic equation `(n^2 + n)/2 = a`.

Comment: I tried this with the following numbers [3, 6, 10] = 19, adding 6 to this sum give me 25 so 4*(4+1) = 20, 20/2 = 10 but 25 - 10 gives me 15...I want to tell if a number is repeated and which one is? WHich branch of mathematics is this?

Comment: These do not conform to your problem description. These numbers do not belong to 1..3. More than that, 4 is not N, but N+1. As for branch, it is elementary combinatorics.

Comment: And if you take arbitrary numbers in this problem, it becomes basically unsolvable unless you know the sum of all distinct numbers in advance.

Comment: OK Im lost here - basically I have the SUM and the number of numbers - but need to know what numnber was duplicated

Comment: But your problem description states that all those numbers belong to `1..N`, where `N+1` is a number of numbers! That is, there are all numbers from 1 to N and one duplicate, also between 1 and N. See an example: N = 5, numbers are 1,2,3,4,5,3. The duplicate is 3. The sum of all numbers is 18. N is 5, we have N+1 = 6 numbers here. So d is = 18 - 5*6/2 = 3, as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, you have:

```
X = 1 + 2 + ... + N + p,  where 1<=p<=N
```

Or

```
X = N(N+1)/2 + p, 1<=p<=N
```

Declare:

```
S(N) = N(N+1)/2
```

And you know that

```
S(N) < X < S(N+1), because 1<=p<=N
```

You can find N, by finding the S(N) such that S(N)X.

If you have found S(N), subtract it from X and you find the duplicate number.