# The best possible searching technique for a large range of input data

Tags: data-structures, language-agnostic

There are 1Billion numbers from 1 to 1Billion but there is one number missing. They are all randomly available, how will you find the missing one in best possible way.

- randomly available means are they randomly distributed throughout the array (i.e. 5984,1,10937658, 20 ...)

Comment: What does "randomly available" mean? Are they in an array? Are the numbers in sequence (i.e. 1,2,3,4,...), or are they randomly distributed throughout the array (i.e. 5984,1,10937658,...)?

Comment: Your question is not well specified. Perhaps this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492302/easy-interview-question-got-harder-given-numbers-1-100-find-the-missing-number will help.

Comment: As the question I linked above says, the sum of numbers from 1 to N is `((N^2)+N)/2`. So if you know that the numbers are from 1 to 1 billion, with one missing, you just sum them, subtract the sum from the expected number, and that's your missing number.

Answer (score 1):

These are only theoretical considerations,but if the numbers are sorted `1,2,3...1B` so you just can split your number group into to parts `1 ... 0.5B` and `0.5B ... 1B` then check how much elements are in first group: if there are less than `0.5B` elements thats means missing value is between `1` and `0.5B`, if there are `0.5B` elements thats means missing value is between `0.5B` and `1B`. Go ahead with the process until you find the missing value.

I do not know whether this is a very quick way, but it is certainly faster than checking each value :D

Maybe it puts you on the road

Answer (score 1):

If limited memory is concern,
Start XORing each number from initially. Then XOR with 1 to 1B. The number that will remain is the missing number.

Something like this:

`Input-1 XOR Input-2 XOR Input-3 XOR Input-last XOR ... XOR 1 XOR 2 XOR...XOR 1B`.

If you have ample of memory, sort all numbers and search sequentially.

First one is `O(N)` while second one is `O(NlogN)`

Smaller set example:

```
1 xor 3 xor 1 xor 2 xor 3 => 2
```

Comment: I don't know why you would ever want to sort (`Ɵ(N)` space, `Ω(N) ∩ O(N log N)` time) if you could use the very elegant and fast XOR trick (`Ɵ(1)` space, `Ɵ(N)` time).