# missing numbers

Tags: c, range, element

Given an array of size n. It contains numbers in the range 1 to n. Each number is present at 
least once except for 2 numbers. Find the missing numbers. 
eg. an array of size 5
elements are suppose 3,1,4,4,3

one approach is

```
static int k;
for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
  for(j=0;j<n;j++)
  {
    if(i==a[j])
      break;
   }
    if(j==n)
    {
      k++;
      printf("missing element is", a[j]);
    }

  if(k==2)
    break;}
```

another solution can be..
for(i=0;i

Comment: @dreamer: Remember to upvote useful answers (once you have the right) and accept the most useful answer (earliest if multiple were most useful).

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492302/easy-interview-question-got-harder-given-numbers-1-100-find-the-missing-number

Comment: hmmm ... `for (j = 0; j < n; j++) if (j == n) /* never happens */;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `qsort()` to sort the array, then loop over it once to find the missing values. Average O(n*log(n)) time because of the sort, and minimal constant additional storage.

Answer (score 4):

Let me First explain the **concept**:

You know that sum of natural numbers 1....n is 
**(n*(n+1))/2**.Also you know the sum of square of sum of first n natural numbers 1,2....n is  **n*(n+1)*(2n+1)/6**.Thus you could solve the above problem in O(n) time using above concept.

**Also if space complexity is not of much consideration you could use count based approach which requires O(n) time and space complexity**.

For more detailed solution visit [Find the two repeating elements in a given array](http://geeksforgeeks.org/?p=7953)

Comment: the two missing numbers here are replaced by some other numbers between i to n..(each number is present atleast once).. so ur logic does not work for this case..

Answer (score 2):

I like the "use array elements as indexes" method from Algorithmist's [link](http://geeksforgeeks.org/?p=7953).

> Method 5 (Use array elements as index)
>   Thanks to Manish K. Aasawat for suggesting this method.

```
traverse the list for i= 1st to n+2 elements
{
check for sign of A[abs(A[i])] ;
if positive then
   make it negative by   A[abs(A[i])]=-A[abs(A[i])];
else  // i.e., A[abs(A[i])] is negative
   this   element (ith element of list) is a repetition
}
```

The only difference is that here it would be traversing 1 to n.
Notice that this is a single-pass solution that uses no extra space (besides storing `i`)!

Footnote:

**Technically** it "steals" some extra space -- essentially it is the counter array solution, but instead of allocating its own array of ints, it uses the sign bits of the original array as counters.

Comment: This only returns the repeated numbers and not the missing numbers

Answer (score 1):

I haven't checked or run this code, but you should get the idea.

```c
int print_missing(int *arr, size_t length) {
  int *new_arr = calloc(sizeof(int) * length);
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    new_arr[arr[i]] = 1;
  }
  for(i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if(!new_arr[i]) {
      printf("Number %i is missing\n", i);
    }
  }
  free(new_arr);
  return 0;
}
```

Runtime should be O(2n). Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: `new_arr` is one element short. `i` can be equal to `length`. Similarly, the second loop should be `for (i = 1; i <= length; i++)`.

Comment: this is taking a space complexity of o(n)... wat to do if there is a space constraint..

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear why the naive approach (you could use a bitfield or an array) of marking the items you have seen isn't just fine. O(2n) CPU, O(n/8) storage.

Comment: for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
while((a[i]!=i+1)&&(a[i]!=a[a[i]-1])
swap(a[i],a[a[i]-1]);
}
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
if(a[i]!=i+1)
printf("%d is missing",i+1);
}

this takes o(n) time nd no extra space..

Comment: @dreamer: I'm not sure I buy this answer.  Even ignoring that you are changing the source array which might not be good (but apparently is for you).  Consider array[3,1,3,3,2] (missing 4,5).  Your look will run infinitely since a[i] and a[a[i]-1] have the same (incorrect) value and you never change i.

Comment: when the a[i] and a[a[i]-1] will have the same value then the loop terminates.. while loop checks a[i]!=a[a[i]-1].. pay close attention to it..

Comment: @robertson.. the value of the source array is not changed.. its just swapped.. even wen we do sorting tht applies.. i dont think tht can be of concern..

Answer (score 0):

If you are free to choose the language, then use python's sets.

```
numbers = [3,1,4,4,3]
print set (range (1 , len (numbers) + 1) ) - set (numbers)
```

Yields the output

```
set([2, 5])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. C# solution:

```
static IEnumerable<int> FindMissingValuesInRange( int[] numbers )
{
  HashSet<int> values = new HashSet<int>( numbers ) ;

  for( int value = 1 ; value <= numbers.Length ; ++value )
  {
    if ( !values.Contains(value) ) yield return value ;
  }
}
```

Comment: i am afraid that you didn't saw the tag "C".Could you please elucidate your approach.

Comment: @Algorithmist: I did see it (in fact, I put it there). I'm just not going to do somebody's homework for them. Elucidation: The source array is a bag; from that derive the set of values it contains. From the set of integers 1-N inclusive, return those missing from the initial set of values.

Answer (score 0):

I see a number of problems with your code. First off, `j==n` will never happen, and that doesn't give us the missing number. You should also initialize `k` to 0 before you attempt to increment it. I wrote an algorithm similar to yours, but it works correctly. However, it is not any faster than you expected yours to be:

```
int k = 0;
int n = 5;
bool found = false;
int a[] = { 3, 1, 4, 4, 3 };

for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{
  for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
  {
    if(a[j] == i)
    {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
  }
  if(!found)
  {
      printf("missing element is %d\n", i);
      k++;
      if(k==2)
        break;
  }
  else
      found = false;
}
```

H2H

Answer (score 0):

using a support array you can archeive O(n)

```
int support[n];

// this loop here fills the support array with the
// number of a[i]'s occurences
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    support[a[i]] += 1; 

// now look which are missing (or duplicates, or whatever)
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    if(support[i] == 0) printf("%d is missing", i);
```

Answer (score 0):

**

```
 for(i=0; i < n;i++) 
{   

while((a[i]!=i+1)&&(a[i]!=a[a[i]-1])
{

swap(a[i],a[a[i]-1]); 
} 

for(i=0;i< n;i++) 
{ 
if(a[i]!=i+1) 
printf("%d is missing",i+1); } 
this takes o(n) time    and o(1) space
```

========================================**

Answer (score 0):

We can use the following code to find duplicate and missing values:

```
    int size = 8;
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 5, 1, 3};
    int result[] = new int[size];

    for(int i =0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        if(result[arr[i]-1] == 1)
        {
            System.out.println("repeating: " + (arr[i]));
        }
        result[arr[i]-1]++;
    }

    for(int i =0; i < result.length; i++)
    {
        if(result[i] == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("missing: " + (i+1));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an interview question: Missing Numbers.
condition 1 : The array must not contain any duplicates.
The complete solution is :

```
public class Solution5 {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int a[] = { 1,8,6,7,10};
    Arrays.sort(a);
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
int start = a[0];
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    int ch = a[i];   
    if(start == ch) {
        start++;
    }else {
     list.add(start);
     start++;
     //must do this 
     i--;
    }
}//for
System.out.println(list);
}//main

}
```