# find 3 missing numbers from a list of 97 unique

Tags: c++, c, arrays, algorithm, traversal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Easy interview question got harder: given numbers 1..100, find the missing number(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492302/easy-interview-question-got-harder-given-numbers-1-100-find-the-missing-numbe)

Given a list (or array) of 97 numbers, each number is unique and between 1 and 100. How to  find three missing numbers from the list ?  complexity of the algorithm ?

My solution:

```
 find3missing(int* array)
 {
 int newarray[100] = {0};

 For i = 0 to 99 
  ++newarray[array[i]] ; 

 For i = 0 to 99
If newarray[i] != 1
    Cout << “the missing number is ” << i+1 << endl ;
 }

 O(n).
```

Any better solutions ?

thanks

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do better than `O(n)` since you still have to look at all the elements.

Comment: Ya You must operate on all n numbers so O(n) is unavoidable

Comment: Your solution needs O(n) additional space. It is possible to do better.

Comment: The first 99 should be 96, else you access array[97]...array[99] which don't exist.