# There is an array having 1 to 100 numbers randomly placed. But two numbers are missing from the list. What are those two numbers?

Tags: algorithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Easy interview question got harder: given numbers 1..100, find the missing number(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492302/easy-interview-question-got-harder-given-numbers-1-100-find-the-missing-numbe)

I know there is better solution than taking sum and then difference from sum of all 100 numbers and then searching for all possibilities. I was asked about this question in an interview. They also told me that i cant use hasing or sorting

Comment: This has already been solved, please see the following:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492302/easy-interview-question-got-harder-given-numbers-1-100-find-the-missing-numbe/3492967#3492967