# How to find a missing number from a list?

Tags: python

How do I find the missing number from a sorted list the pythonic way?

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10]
```

I have come across this [post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/24520/finding-missing-items-in-an-int-list/) but is there a more and efficient way to do this?

Comment: There is a generalization of this problem! Refer the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492302/easy-interview-question-got-harder-given-numbers-1-100-find-the-missing-numbe

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
>>> a=[1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10]
>>> sum(xrange(a[0],a[-1]+1)) - sum(a)
6
```

alternatively (using the sum of AP series formula)

```
>>> a[-1]*(a[-1] + a[0]) / 2 - sum(a)
6
```

For generic cases when multiple numbers may be missing, you can formulate an O(n) approach.

```
>>> a=[1,2,3,4,7,8,10]
>>> from itertools import imap, chain
>>> from operator import sub
>>> print list(chain.from_iterable((a[i] + d for d in xrange(1, diff))
                        for i, diff in enumerate(imap(sub, a[1:], a))
                        if diff > 1))
[5, 6, 9]
```

Comment: What if 1, 2, 3 are missing?

Comment: Question says `How to find missing number` and not `How to find amissing numbers`

Comment: @thefourtheye: Check my update for a generic case with multiple gaps

Comment: If the missing number is the highest or lowest one, ie. either 1 or 10 in his list is missing, then the above algorithm doesn't work, but that's nitpicking.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: Then we can argue if those numbers are actually missing, or, they are not  supposed to be in the list.

Comment: How about `set(a).symmetric_difference(xrange(a[0], a[-1] + 1))` for the second example?

Comment: @JonClements: I do not have timing data, to suport if set operation might be faster. Also, in any case the final result needs to be sorted

Comment: @Abhijit Not necessarily... that's a constraint you've implied yourself when offering the multiple number solution. I was just offering a more readable (not necessarily faster) - and a sort afterwards isn't exactly difficult :)

Comment: I get `sub is not defined`

Comment: @Veehmot: Just import sub from operator as `from operator import sub`

Answer (score 16):

This should work:

```
a = [1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10]
b = [x for x in range(a[0], a[-1] + 1)]
a = set(a)
print(list(a ^ set(b)))
>>> [2, 6]
```

Comment: Elegant solution, which doesn't involve extra modules (which is the case with the solution provided by @Abhijit). The only issue (not sure if it exists!) is the conversion to a set. If the list already contains unique numbers, I'm not sure what the performance impact would be when the `set()` conversion is applied. Sadly the `^` operator only works on sets hence the conversion needs to take place even when one knows that the list is actually a set (though stored as a list).

Comment: @rbaleksandar I believe the set allows one to perform the symmetric difference between the two "lists".

Comment: Hi, sorry for jumping into your answer this late. Wondering if you could enlighten me why for the range, the last element need to be added with a value of 1? I tried without it and I am still able to get the same answer..

Comment: @dissidia `range(0,10)` would only cover the values from 0 to 9, inclusive. To also cover 10, 1 is added to the last value of `a`. Of course, it doesn't really matter because if 10 were missing from `a`, how would we know about that?

Answer (score 8):

```
1 + 2 + 3 + ... + (n - 1) + n = (n) * (n + 1)/2
```

so the missing number is:

```
(a[-1] * (a[-1] + 1))/2 - sum(a)
```

Comment: Your answer is correct, but given your first sentence, it would make a lot more sense if you actually used that fact in the answer, ie remove the first part and replace it with the product...

Comment: Modified it to be relevant to the problem at hand.

Answer (score 7):

```
set(range(a[len(a)-1])[1:]) - set(a)
```

Take the set of all numbers minus the set of given.

Comment: `range(a[0],a[-1]+1)` ?

Comment: @kelvinss I was thinking that his array is beginning from 1 always because he asked what if 1,2,3 are missing

Comment: I realized that the `+1` in the second argument doesn't matter. But I think `range(1,a[-1])` is more clear.

Comment: I believe this is the most concise solution that solves the general case. The other algorithms mentioned don't account for gaps. E.g. `a=[1, 2, 4, 99]`. Your method handles this appropriately.

Answer (score 7):

And another `itertools` way:

```
from itertools import count, izip

a=[1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10]
nums = (b for a, b in izip(a, count(a[0])) if a != b)
next(nums, None)
# 6
```

Answer (score 2):

This will handle the cases when the first or last number is missing.

```py
>>> a=[1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10]
>>> n = len(a) + 1
>>> (n*(n+1)/2) - sum(a)
6
```

Answer (score 1):

If many missing numbers in list:

```
>>> a=[1,2,3,4,5,7,8,10]
>>> [(e1+1) for e1,e2 in zip(a, a[1:]) if e2-e1 != 1]
[6, 9]
```

Comment: You might want to say `e2-e1 != 1`

Comment: What if `a=[1,2,3,4,5,8,10]`

Answer (score 1):

```
def find(arr):
        for x in range(0,len(arr) -1):
                if arr[x+1] - arr[x] != 1:
                        print arr[x] + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution for the above problem, it also finds multiple missing elements.

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,8,9,10]
missing_element = []
for i in range(a[0], a[-1]+1):
    if i not in a:
        missing_element.append(i)

print missing_element
```

o/p:
[6,7]

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simple logic for finding mising numbers in list.

```
l=[-10,-5,2,4,5,9,20]
s=l[0]
e=l[-1]
x=sorted(range(s,e+1))
l_1=[]
for i in x:
    if i not in l:
        l_1.append(i)
print(l_1)
```

Comment: all missing numbers will be added to the   (  l_1 ) list.

Answer (score 1):

```
def findAllMissingNumbers(a):
   b = sorted(a)
   return list(set(range(b[0], b[-1])) - set(b))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
L=[-5,1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10,13,55]

missing=[]

for i in range(L[0],L[-1]):
    if i not in L:
        missing.append(i)
print(missing)
```

Comment: Hi Joe, with 17 other answers already present, it would be great if you could add an explanation to your code to help us understand how it is different from other answers and how it solves the problem in the way that other answers dont. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A simple list comprehension approach that will work with multiple (non-consecutive) missing numbers.

```
def find_missing(lst):
    """Create list of integers missing from lst."""
    return [lst[x] + 1 for x in range(len(lst) - 1) 
            if lst[x] + 1 != lst[x + 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a perfectly working solution by @Abhiji. I would like to extent his answer by the option to define a granularity value. This might be necessary if the list should be checked for a missing `value > 1`:

```
from itertools import imap, chain
from operator import sub

granularity = 3600
data = [3600, 10800, 14400]

print list(
  chain.from_iterable(
    (data[i] + d for d in xrange(1, diff) if d % granularity == 0) 
      for i, diff in enumerate(imap(sub, data[1:], data)) 
        if diff > granularity
  )
)
```

The code above would produce the following output: `[7200]`.

As this code snipped uses a lot of nested functions, I'd further like to provide a  quick back reference, that helped me to understand the code:

- [Python enumerate()](https://www.codecademy.com/en/forum_questions/5087f2d786a27b02000041a9)
- [Python imap()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html)
- [Python chain.from_iterable()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45874791/1280289)

Answer (score 0):

Less efficient for very large lists, but here's my version for the Sum formula:

```
def missing_number_sum(arr):
    return int((arr[-1]+1) * arr[-1]/2) - sum(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the range is known and the list is given, the below approach will work.

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10]
missingValues = [i for i in range(1, 10+1) if i not in a]
print(missingValues)

# o/p: [6]
```

Answer (score 0):

An interesting solution is leveraging [enumerate](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/enumerate-in-python/)
and its ability to track indexes!

With your example, I see you begin your range at 1.
Lets assume in these examples that our range always begins at 1.

Example 1:
If you only need to find the first occurrence

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10]

# Offsetting the index to align with when the range begins
index_offset = 1
for index, num in enumerate(a):
    expected_num = index + index_offset
    if num != expected_num:
        print(expected_num)
        break
```

**The resulting output is: 6**

Example 2:
How about if you need to find all occurrences of a missing number?
That could look something like this:

```
a = [2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10]

missing_nums = []

# Initially offsetting the index to align with when range begins
index_offset = 1
for index, num in enumerate(a):
    expected_num = index + index_offset
    if num != expected_num:
        missing_nums.append(expected_num)
        # Increment the offset to account for this missing num
        index_offset += 1

print(missing_nums)
```

**The resulting output is: [1, 6, 9]**

Answer (score -1):

```
set(range(1,a[-1])) | set(a)
```

Compute the union of two sets.

Answer (score -1):

I used index position.
this way i compare index and value.

```
a=[0,1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10]

for i in a:
  print i==a.index(i)
```

Comment: Doesn't give the expected result.

Comment: This is not scalable at all and will not work if the array numerals are far off from the index.