# subtract n values from input python

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I haven't found anything even relevant to my question, so i may be asking it wrong.

I am working on an exercise where I am given sequential values starting at 1 and going to n, but not in order.  I must find a missing value from the list.

My method is to add the full 1  => n value in a for loop but I can't figure out how to add n - 1 non-sequential values each as its own line of input in order to subtract it from the full value to get the missing one.

I have been searching modifications to for loops or just how to add n inputs of non-sequential numbers.  If I am simply asking the wrong question, I am happy to do my own research if someone could point me in the right direction.

```
total = 0
for i in range (1 , (int(input())) + 1):
    total += i

print(total)

for s in **?????(int(input()))**:
    total -= s

print(total)
```

sample input:
5
3
2
5
1
expected output: 4

Comment: Please show us the code you've written so far so we can help better

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20718315/how-to-find-a-missing-number-from-a-list) might help.

Comment: added code. sorry for the oversight.

Comment: At first you say you're given a list of values. That would make me think you are writing a function which would take a list as an argument, ie. something in the form `[5, 3, 2, 5, 1]`. But you are trying to write some code that takes command-line input using `input()`? I'm not sure how those two fit together.

Comment: sorry for the confusion.  I am new at this.  The input is n and then n - 1 values all as individual pieces of input. The sample input I gave is 5 individual line items of input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fill in the approach you're using in your example code:

```
total = 0
n = int(input("How long is the sequence? "))
for i in range(1, n+1):
    total += i

for i in range(1, n):
    total -= int(input("Enter value {}: ".format(i)))

print("Missing value is: " + str(total))
```

That first for loop is unnecessary though. First of all, your loop is equivalent to the `sum` function:

```
total = sum(range(1,n+1))
```

But you can do away with any iteration altogether by using the formula:

```
total = int(n*(n+1)/2) # division causes float output so you have to convert back to an int
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you.  I didn't think to take the value as a variable and use it to end the range of the second loop.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are supposed to create the initial data (with the missing item), so I added some lines to generate this sequence:

```
import random

n = 12 # or n = int(input('Enter n: ')) to get user input

# create a shuffled numeric sequence with one missing value
data = list(range(1,n+1))
data.remove(random.randrange(1,n+1))
random.shuffle(data)
print(data)

# create the corresponding reference sequence (without missing value)  
data2 = list(range(1,n+1))

# find missing data with your algorithm
print("Missing value =", sum(data2)-sum(data))
```

Here is the output:

```
[12, 4, 11, 5, 2, 7, 1, 6, 8, 9, 10]
Missing value = 3
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I think my real issue is that I do not get to generate the list myself.  I have n individual items coming in through input().  I can get the first value and deal with that but can't figure out how to handle the remaining n - 1 values, each as individual inputs.

Comment: OK, I didn't understand that from your OP. Do you know the value of **n** before starting the loop over `input()` or do you rely on some specific entered value (e.g. empty line or 0)  to stop the loop ? Because the solution is very different for both cases...