# How to find missing number from a list?

Tags: python

I am breaking on the missing value in the list as subjected. And as well as attached in this question [How to find a missing number from a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20718315/how-to-find-a-missing-number-from-a-list)

How is it including missing value in the sum of range of list as mentioned below?

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10]

sum(xrange(a[0],a[-1]+1)) - sum(a)
```

Result: `6`

Comment: It's using the magic of simple arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

It's as simple as it could be.

Try to break it down and it will be easier to understand:

- ***xrange*** provides you with a generator that will eventually give you
  integers between the two numbers provides as the arguments to this
  function. So xrange(4,9) will give you (4,5,6,7,8). So the main
  takeaway is that xrange here gives integers from 4 till 9(including 4
  and while excluding 9)
- Now the ***sum*** function just adds up the values inside a given object(here list);nothing more to explain here I believe
- So in your case, xrange(a[0],a[-1]+1) resulted into a generator which gives out values from a[0] i.e. 1 till and not including a[-1]+1 i.e. 11. Remember, in Python, negative indexing is referencing from backward. So a[-1] means last term in the list a. Similarly a[-2]=9.
- So now as we got a list of all the numbers b/w 1 to 10 and sum gives out 55 and sum of a itself is equal to 49(since it doesn't include 6), so the difference is your missing value.

Note- One issue with this code is that let's say if there are more than 1 number missing, it will result into the sum of those missing values and not the missing value rather. So if a=[1,2,3,5,8,9,10], then this code will result into:

```
sum(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)-sum(1,2,3,5,8,9,10) and that will be equal to 17
```

***On a sidenote***- xrange is deprecated from Python 3 and I am like 90% sure this question will be marked as a bad one.

Comment: See in Python, the best thing is to work around the code bits by bits and try to understand what each part is doing. Python is one of the easiest and understandable language. Just try to play around with it and you'll start understanding it pretty well. 

Have a lovely day ahead mate.