# How to solve this equation for solving "Finding duplicate in integer array"

Tags: algorithm, equation

I was looking at the problem and the discussion here: [Easy interview question got harder: given numbers 1..100, find the missing number(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492302/easy-interview-question-got-harder-given-numbers-1-100-find-the-missing-numbe)

One of the user provided a solution using following equation.
k1 + k2 = x

k1^2 + k2^2 = y

Substituting provides (x-k2)^2 + k2^2 = y

I am trying to solve this equation further and come up with a C program to solve the problem of finding duplicates.
Inspite of spending lot of time I couldn't solve this equation to get k1 or k2 one side. I always ended up with k1 or k2 on both side of equation.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Search for "how do I solve a quadratic equation".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expand the equation

```
(x - k2)^2 + k2^2 = y
```

and get

```
x^2 - 2xk2 + 2k2^2 = y
```

or

```
2k2^2 - 2xk2 + x^2 - y = 0
```

Now use the formula for solving the quadratic equation `az^2 + bz + c = 0` which is `(-b +/- sqrt(b^2 - 4ac))/2a`. Only that in our case `z=k2`. So

```
k2 = (2x +/- sqrt(4x^2 - 8(x^2 - y))) / 4
```

or

```
k2 = (x +/- sqrt(x^2 - 2(x^2 - y))) / 2

   = (x +/- sqrt(2y - x^2)) / 2
```

and you can put

```
k2 = (x + sqrt(2y - x^2)) / 2
k1 = (x - sqrt(2y - x^2)) / 2.
```

Comment: Thanks, this is really great help.

Comment: @user1150393 Thank you.