# Find lost cards (faster solution)

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization

We're given N (3 <= N <= 50000) cards with unique numbers from 1 to N.
We lost some 3 cards and our goal is to find them.

*Input*: first line contains number of cards N.
Second line contains 3 numbers: sum of all left cards we have, sum of their squares and sum of their cubes.

*Output*: numbers of 3 lost cards in any order.

Here what I tried: I found the same 3 sums for lost cards and then check of possible numbers until three of them satisfy our sums.

Is there a faster solution? I have to pass 2sec time limit in Python with max N = 50000.

```
N = int(input())
lst = list(range(1, N+1))
s_rest, s2_rest, s3_rest = list(map(int, input().split()))

s = sum(lst)
s2 = sum([x**2 for x in lst])
s3 = sum([x**3 for x in lst])
# sums of 3 lost numbers
s_lost = s - s_rest
s2_lost = s2 - s2_rest
s3_lost = s3 - s3_rest


def find_numbers():
    """Find first appropriate option"""
    for num1 in range(s_lost):
        for num2 in range(s_lost):
            for num3 in range(s_lost):
                if (num1 + num2 + num3 == s_lost) and (num1**2 + num2**2 + num3**2 == s2_lost)\
                        and (num1**3 + num2**3 + num3**3 == s3_lost):
                    return (num1, num2, num3)

answer = find_numbers()
print(answer[0], answer[1], answer[2])
```

**Examples**

*Input*:

4

1 1 1

Output:

2 3 4

---

*Input*:

5

6 26 126

Output:

2 3 4

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Easy interview question got harder: given numbers 1..100, find the missing number(s)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492302/easy-interview-question-got-harder-given-numbers-1-100-find-the-missing-numbe)

Comment: Given your N is small (50000 at most), what's wrong with `set(range(1, N+1)).difference(input_numbers)` ? This is a much easier problem than the one I suggested is a dupe given this constraint on N, and a simple set-based problem which uses O(N) storage (rather than O(1) storage) works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your unknown numbers are x,y,z, then you have a system of three equations

```
x + y + z = a  //your s_lost
x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = b  //your s2_lost
x^3 + y^3 + z^3 = c  //your s3_lost
```

While direct solution of this system seems too complex, we can fix one unknown and solve simpler system. For example, check all possible values for z and solve system for x and y

```
 for z in range(s_lost):
 ....
```

Now let's look to new system:

```
 x + y  = a - z = aa
 x^2 + y^2 = b - z^2 = bb
 substitute
 x = aa - y
 (aa - y)^2 + y^2 = bb
 2 * y^2 - 2 * y * aa - bb + aa^2 = 0
 solve this quadratic equation for y
 D = 4 * aa^2 - 8 * (aa^2 - bb) = 8 * bb -4 * aa^2
 y(1,2) = (2*aa +- Sqrt(D)) / 4
```

So for every z value find:
- whether solution gives integer values of y
- then get x
- and then check if cube sum equation is true.

Using this approach you'll get solution with linear complexity O(N) against your cubic complexity O(N^3).

P.S. If rather simple mathematical solution for equation system does exist, it has complexity O(1))

Answer (score 1):

This can be simplified by mathematical approach. You are given 3 equations and have 3 unknowns.

```
sum(1+2+..+N) - x1 - x2 - x3 = a  
sum(1^2+2^2+..+N^2) - x1^2 - x2^2 - x3^3 = b  
sum(1^3+2^3+..+N^3) - x1^3 - x2^3 - x3^3 = c
```

Obviously `sum(1..N)` is `1/2 *N(N+1)`, while `sum(1^2+2^2+3^2+..+N^2)` is `1/6 *N*(N+1)*(2N+1)` and `sum(1^3+2^3+..+N^3)` can be written as `1/4 *N^2 *(N+1)^2`. Here are wolframalpha outputs: [∑k](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%281%2B2%2B..%2BN%29), [∑k^2](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%281%5E2%2B2%5E2%2B3%5E2%2B..%2BN%5E2%29), [∑k^3](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%281%5E3%2B2%5E3%2B..%2BN%5E3%29)

At this point only thing left is solving given system of equations (3 with 3 unknowns is totally solvable) and implementing this. You only need to find one solution which makes it even easier. Running time is O(1).

Answer (score 0):

Surely there exists a faster approach!

For N=50,000 your brute-force function would have to make up to

```
N * N * N = 125,000,000,000,000
```

iterations, so this is not an option.

Additionally, you should check for `num1 == num2` etc. to avoid duplicated numbers (the problem does not state it explicitly, but I understand 'We lost some 3 cards' means you need to find three *different* numbers satisfying the conditions given).

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the list, and find the pairs such that `a[i+1] =/= a[i]+1`. For every such pair numbers `[a[i]+1;a[i+1])` are missing. This would give you O(n log n) running time.

Answer (score 0):

I can give you an idea,

let `sum1 = 1+2+3...n`

let `sum2 = 1^2+2^2+3^2...n`

and `p, q, r` is three numbers given by input consecutively.

We need to search `a, b, c`. Iterate `for c = 1 to N.`

For each iteration,

let `x = sum1 - (p+c)`

let `y = sum2 - (q+c*c)`

so `a+b = x` and `a^2+b^2 = y`.

Since `a^2+b^2 = (a+b)^2 - 2ab`, you can find `2ab` from equation `a^2+b^2 = y`.

`a+b` is known and `ab` is known, by a little math calculation, you can find if there exist a solution for `a` and `b` (it forms quadratic equation). If exist, print the solution and break the iteration.

It's an `O(N)` solution.