# How to find missing number in array

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::sort;
int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    int n;                                  // Enter Size of 2 array
    cin >> n;                               // enter 5
    long long *ptr1 = new long long[n - 1]; // size of array must be less than 5 by one n-1
    for (int x = 0; x < n - 1; x++)
    {
        cin >> ptr1[x];
    }
    sort(ptr1, ptr1 + (n - 1));
    for (int z = 1; z < n; z++)
    {
        if (z != ptr1[x])
        {
            cout << z;
            break;
        }
        x++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You're given all positive integers from 1,2,…,n except one integer. Find the missing integer.

Input
The first line of input contains an integer n (2≤n≤2×105).

The second line of input contains n−1 distinct integers from 1 to n (inclusive).

Output
Print the missing integer.
when i try to sumbit this code i get wrong in test 10 but i don't know why! and he didn't show the test so what is wrong?

Comment: You don't need to store all the number, or sort anything, or search for anything. Consider the sum of the numbers from 1 to n, and compare to the sum of the numbers in the input.

Comment: You mention "test 10", what is this test? What is the input for that specific test? Have you tried to use a debugger to step through the code to see what happens with that input?

Comment: You can consider [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492302/easy-interview-question-got-harder-given-numbers-1-100-find-the-missing-numbe) Q&A for a better algorithmic approach (as @molbdnilo pointed out).

Comment: You don't re-init `x` for second loop.

Comment: Side note (see @molbdnilo): Sum of numbers from 1 to n can be calculated as `n * (n+1) / 2` – just for the case you *might* not yet know...

Comment: Actually you have a memory leak for not `delete[]`ing the array again... As C++, you should rather use `std::vector` instead: `std::vector<long long> v; v.reserve(n) /* avoids unnecessary reallocations */; for(...) { int val; std::cin >> val; v.push_back(val); } std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());`.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this in a more straightforward way if you subtract the numbers that were entered from the expected sum of all numbers 1, 2, ..., n (see comments by @molbdnilo, @Aconcagua and @marcus-müller):

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::size_t n;
    std::cin >> n;
    
    std::size_t sum{ n*(n + 1)/2 };
    for (std::size_t idx = 1; idx != n; ++idx) {
        std::size_t thisNumber;
        std::cin >> thisNumber;
        sum -= thisNumber;
    }
    
    std::cout << "Missing number: " << sum << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: if we're aiming for shortest solution: start by calculating the expected sum, and in your your `for`-loop, simply subtract from that sum successively. In the end, what remains in the sum variable is the missing number.

Comment: Thanks – but I added only the total sum, @molbdnilo hinted to the algorithm itself and actually deserves the credits...

Answer (score 0):

I have a three-fold answer:

1. This program leaks memory
2. You included `<algorithm>` please use it. (Look on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/))
3. Spoilers `vector`, `iota`, `mismatch`

Also, you don't reset `x` before the second loop.
That's never going to work unless the missing integer is the last of the array, and not equal to `1`

```cpp
  // for (... z)
    if (z != ptr1[x] /* Here */) {
      // print 1, end loop OR invoke undefined behavior
    }
    x++; // Now x is equal to (n - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems with your code:

```cpp
long long *ptr1 = new long long[n - 1];
```

You call `new`, without `delete`. This will create a memory leak.

You haven't reinitialized `x`, so any access to `ptr1[x]` is out-of-bounds.

Slove all of that, and your code will look like:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
int main()
{
    int n;                                  
    cin >> n;                               
    std::vector<int> vec(n-1); // std::vector instead
    for (int x = 0; x < n - 1; x++)
    {
        std::cin >> vec[x];
    }
    std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
    int x = 0; // use another variable instead of reused the old one.
    for (int z = 1; z < n; z++)
    {
        if (z != vec[x])
        {
            std::cout << z;
            break;
        }
        x++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But, this isn't the best approach anyway. As @molbdnilo suggest:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;

    int sum{};
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i)
    {
        int tmp;
        std::cin >> tmp;
        sum += tmp;
    }
    std::cout << (n + 1) * n / 2 - sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Building blocks:

- The expected sum: `int expected_sum = n * (n + 1) / 2;`
- The sum of all integers fed to the test after you've read `n`:

  ```
  #include <iterator> // istream_iterator
  #include <numeric>  // accumulate
  int sum = std::accumulate(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin),
                            std::istream_iterator<int>{}, 0);
  ```
- Now, `expected_sum - sum` should give you the missing value.