# Find the 2 removed numbers from an array of all numbers 1-n

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

> Find the 2 removed numbers from an array of all numbers 1...n. The array order is randomized *and* no hashmaps are allowed.

I got the following hints:

- Mark the 2 numbers with x and y... (But I'm not sure what to do with that)
- Maybe use the sum somehow?

At the end I wasn't told the correct solution and I still have no clue.

Of course, a O(nlogn) algorithm is easy, but the challenge asks for a O(n) time complexity.

With no hashmaps/hashsets allowed, I didn't see how to approach this. I mean, how is this possible without them?

How could we find the two missing numbers in O(n) time?

Comment: Related question: [Easy interview question got harder: given numbers 1-100, find the missing numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492302/easy-interview-question-got-harder-given-numbers-1-100-find-the-missing-numbe?rq=1)

Comment: This is a much easier problem that the linked "dupe" because it doesn't have an O(1) space constraint. For example, create an array of N bits, set bits corresponding to the input values, then find the zero bits. This is easy and obviously O(N) time.

Comment: And the "dupe" doesn't allow array mutation, excluding the relatively simple in-place algorithm: partition the numbers with a pivot halfway through the range. Either both missing numbers are in the same partition (repeat with a problem half the original size), or they're on opposite sides (solve the "one missing number" problem but with an arbitrary range). This is O(N) time and O(1) additional space.

Comment: @PaulHankin "create an array of N bits*" That would be a hash table.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI I can see an argument for that and arguments against, but if this obvious solution is intended to be excluded, wouldn't the question be better worded?

Comment: The interviewer is a human too.

Comment: @PaulHankin I do believe that if hashmaps were not allowed, then any variation of it would also not be allowed... Though I don't know myself since I didn't think of it at the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could calculate what the sum and the sum of squares is of the given numbers, and compare that with what those sums would have been if the array would have also included the two missing values  and .

This gives you two equations:

- +  =
- ² + ² =

Where  is the difference between the "expected" sum and the actual sum, and  is the difference of the expected sum of squares and the actual sum of squares.

By substituting , the above can be rewritten as:

- 2² − 2 + ²− = 0

The two solutions to that equation are the values for  and :

- = [ ± √(2 − ²)] / 2

Here is an implementation in JavaScript, where two random numbers are removed from a sequence from 1 to 20, and the algorithm retrieves the missing values (as the algorithm doesn't use the order of the input, I didn't bother to shuffle the input):

```js
function createInput(n) {
    const arr = [...Array(n+1).keys()]; // {0,1,...,n}
    arr.shift(); // Remove 0 => {1,...,n}
    for (let removals = 1; removals <= 2; removals++) {
        const i = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
        arr.splice(i, 1); // Remove random element
    }
    return arr;
}

function findXY(arr) {
    const n = arr.length + 2;
    // Expected sum and sumOfSquares
    let sum = n * (n + 1) / 2;
    let sumSquares = sum * (2 * n + 1) / 3;
    // Subtract the actual sums
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        sum -= arr[i];
        sumSquares -= arr[i] * arr[i];
    }
    // Solution to quadratic equation
    const x = (sum - Math.sqrt(2 * sumSquares - sum * sum)) / 2;
    return [x, sum - x];
}

for (let run = 1; run <= 4; run++) {
    const arr = createInput(20);
    console.log("input  : ", ...arr);
    console.log("missing: ", ...findXY(arr));
}
```

Comment: Looking at the product is probably unreasonable for any big n; Instead of looking at sum and product, you could look at sum and sum of squares. This gives x+y=q, x^2+y^2=p; which can be solved nicely using symmetric coefficients. Also, q and p can be calculated directly using q = n(n+1)/2 and p = n(n+1)(2n+1)/6.

Comment: Thanks, @Stef, that is a good remark. I switched the method to use the sum of squares as you proposed.

Comment: Thank you! I do believe the sum of squares was the solution he was expecting, since you can generalize it for more numbers removed